# Как парсить doc и docx на php без использования сторонних библиотек?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doc, docx

Подскажите, пожалуйста как парсить документы типа doc и docx без использования библиотек на php?

Comment: Если вы по какой-то причине не можете использовать готовую библиотеку (учитывая формулировку вопроса, вам именно это и следует сделать), то прочитать её исходники, разобраться и повторить функционал, вам никто не мешает - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: Библиотеку использовать не получается, поэтому надо использовать что-то свое, понятное дело, что проще повторить что-то готовое, но если нет столько времени, чтобы разбираться.

Comment: Формат docx нужно 1)расжать 2) найти файл с документом, и выполнив допустим несложный xsl запрос можно из xml вытянуть текст, или попробовать её пережевать вручную.

Comment: Формат doc - читать обвертку biff8. Как вариант - начиная с 0xA00 как правило в юникоде идёт текст. Страницы по 512 байт, написав небольшой "фильтр страницы" можно получить текст (я так делал).